# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset while on vpn

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am trying to send get request to a url which is blocked by the isp. therefore i need to connect through a vpn. after connecting to vpn i am able to reach that url in the browser and also in postman. but in the java application when trying to connect using `UniRest` or `RestTemplate` , i get `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset`;

other urls are ok and can be reached by java application. even same blocked urls which require a vpn.
here is how the code looks like:

```
SSLContext sslContext= SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null,new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .setProtocol("TLSv1.2")
                .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf=new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .setConnectionReuseStrategy(NoConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .build();
        Unirest.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        final var body = Unirest.get(new URL(BASE_URL)).asString().getBody();
```

i have tried various ways i found in SO, but none of them helped me. including keeping connection alive like this:

```
ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy myStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
            @Override
            public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
                        (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                    String param = he.getName();
                    String value = he.getValue();
                    if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase
                            ("timeout")) {
                        return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                    }
                }
                return 5 * 1000;
            }
        };

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager
                = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy)
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .build();
        Unirest.setHttpClient(client );
        final var body = Unirest.get(new URL(BASE_URL)).asString().getBody();
```

this didn't work either;

i'm using java 11;